# UINavigationBar Custom Right Bar Button in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I am adding a custom button with image on the right side of the `UINavigationBar` in Xamarin.iOS,
But unfortunately does not succeed yet. The problem is that it always shows a button with a blue background.
This is my code:

```
    var customBtn = new UIBarButtonItem ();
    customBtn.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("home.png");
    customBtn.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This button is clicked");
    };

    NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = customBtn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to use `SetRightBarButtonItems` like so:

```
var rightButton = new UIButton (UIButtonType.Custom);
rightButton.SetImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("home"), UIControlState.Normal);
rightButton.SetImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("home"), UIControlState.Disabled);
rightButton.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, 17, 17); // set this to the size of the image

var rightBarButton = new UIBarButtonItem (rightButton);
navItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(new UIBarButtonItem[] {rightBarButton }, false);
rightButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
    Console.WriteLine("This button is clicked");
};
```